# 'valid signing identity not found' Error in all profile in organizer

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: Person's Name (XXXXXXXX)' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

In organizer, I click on Provision Profiles and the provision profile I downloaded. Underneath I get the warning:

**A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain**

I've looked up many, many other people that had this problem, but all seem to resolve it by deleting the cert and provision

i also tried this but same problem once

i have one profile without postfix  bundle id  without error

Any help most well come..........

Comment: hey dinesh, you will have to reset certificate and again you will have to download certificate and profile.you will have to do this if the certificate is not created on your mac because every certificate has distinct mac id attached with certificate.so if while downloading mac id will not match then there is only one option and that you will have to revoke certificate my friend!!!

Comment: hi..do you have arrow sign on certificate in keychain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check that your certificate is valid or invalid from `Keychain Access`

Here this type of Error occur if certificate expired.

And also set valid certificate which you want to use in `Build Setting - > Code Signing Identifire` of Project's `Target` and also `Project`

And at last set Identifire in `Targets -> Summary -> Builde Identifile` for Example `com.IdentifireCertiFicateName.yourProject`

i hope this help you....

Answer (score 0):

your certificate process at the first time you create `CSR` file. from that you work on the developer provisioning profile and distribution profile. if you change the system you have to export the `certficate` and `privatekey` from `keychain access -> my Certificate` expand and export your certificate and privatekey file in `.p12` format. install those file in your current system. after that set `codesing` in `project` and `target` file.